# Dealing with many parameters/class attributes in Python

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I'm creating a Python class that will use its parameters to define two other classes within this class. For example, `ClassA` contains `ClassB` and `ClassC`. Because of this, ClassA has a lot of parameters.

I'm currently solving this using `**kwargs` for `classB` and `classC` arguments, and saving only the input parameters for `classA` parameters. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3, **kwargs):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
        self.a3 = a3

        # Get B and C kwargs
        default_params = {
            'b1': kwargs.get('b1', 1),
            'b2': kwargs.get('b1', 2),
            'c1': kwargs.get('c1', 1),
            'c2': kwargs.get('c1', 2),          
        }
        for param in default_params:
            self.__dict__[param] = default_params[param]

        B = classB(a1=self.a1, b1=self.b1, b2=self.b2)
        C = classC(a2=self.a2, c1=self.c1, c2=self.c2)
```

Is this a worse solution compared to the below?

```
class A:
    def __init__(
        self,
        a1, a2, a3,
        b1, b2, c1, c2):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
        self.a3 = a3
        self.b1 = b1
        self.b2 = b2
        self.c1 = c1
        self.c2 = c2
```

My concern is if arguments for class B and C are super numerous, then class A's attributes seems too many. On the other hand, the first approach seems to take up more lines anyway.

Another way is if I pass only kwargs to `classB` and `classC`, but this will have an error when there are some parameters not present in one of the classes.

Is there a pythonic way I'm failing to see here for classes with many attributes and utilising this kind of design pattern?

Comment: Some parts of this design seem weird, can you clarify them? Why do you take ``**kwargs``, when the rest of the code explicitly works with ``b1``, ``b2``, ``c1``, ``c2`` arguments (indirectly as keys)? Why do you store the arguments (``self.b1``, ...) when you just want to pass them on?

Comment: Note that style question may be more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Make sure to check their [How To Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page to provide all relevant information.

Comment: That's a good question. For using `**kwargs*, I was thinking if a user gives a specific value for `b1` for example, then I can get it from `kwargs` without defining the long list of attributes. For the 2nd question, I was planning to log the parameters in a separate file, although you're right I don't think I actually need to store it as `self.b1`

Comment: I have tried codereview previously, but they require real project code which I'm not able to provide. I've created a minimal reproducible example here which is more widely accepted in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary criteria should be to avoid emulating what Python provides natively – namely parameters and defaults, as well as instance attributes.

Since `__init__` already knows all the attributes and defaults it expects (via `default_params`), add them to the signature directly. Avoid storing arguments for `classB` and `classC` on `A` – if needed, fetch them from the instances.

```py
class A:
    # handle parameters/defaults natively
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3, b1=1, b2=2, c1=1, c2=2):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
        self.a3 = a3
        # do not store B/C attributes, store B/C directly
        self.b = classB(a1=self.a1, b1=b1, b2=b2)
        self.c = classC(a2=self.a2, c1=c1, c2=c2)
```

This is functionally equivalent to the first case (minus exposing all arguments) but uses native Python functionality.

---

If `A` has to provide additional functionality, *add* them explicitly:

- If `A` should take (and ignore) additional parameters, have an *additional* catch-all `**kwargs`:

  ```py
  class A:
      # discard additional parameters/defaults explicitly
      def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3, b1=1, b2=2, c1=1, c2=2, **_):
          ...
  ```
- If `A` should expose `classB` and/or `classC` fields, provide them from the instances.

  ```py
  class A:
      ...

      @property
      def b1(self):
          return self.b.b1
  ```

Comment: This is very helpful and informative, thank you! Could you point out where I should go to for learning these useful code styles?